# How to derive the analytic formula of this integral?

Tags: integration

If $F(t) = \int_0^\infty  {{{(1 + x)}^t}{e^{ - x}}dx} $, is it possible to get an analytical formula for $F(t)$?

Thanks!

Comment: make a substitution $y=1+x$. Afterwards look up the definition of the incomplete $\Gamma$-function and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Notice, following formula of Laplace transform $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt=L[f(t)]=f(s)$$ &

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}t^n dx =L[t^n]=\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{s^{n+1}}$$

Comment: $F(t) = \int_0^\infty  {{{(1 + x)}^t}{e^{ - sx}}dx}  = {e^s}\int_1^\infty  {{y^t}{e^{ - sy}}dy}  = {e^s}\left( {\int_0^\infty  {{y^t}{e^{ - sy}}dy}  - \int_0^1 {{y^t}{e^{ - sy}}dy} } \right)$

Comment: $ \Rightarrow F(t) = {e^s}\left( {\frac{{\Gamma (t + 1)}}{{{s^{t + 1}}}} - \int_0^1 {{y^t}{e^{ - sy}}dy} } \right)$